# SCSS Inheritance with parameter

Tags: css, sass, extend, scss-mixins

I'm using inheritance to set some styles.
The whole context is into a mixin. For that reason, I cant define another mixin with parameter.

Is there some option, to place parameter in the `%ImgSize` inheritance?
This example is greatly simplified. In my application I would save a lot of code if the said option is possible.

```scss
@mixin imageSize($theme) {
  .someClass {
    @extend %ImgSize;
  }

  .someClass2 {
    @extend %ImgSize;
  }

  %ImgSize {
    // some calculations with different variables
  }
}
```

Comment: Hallo spiegelbirke, I struggle to understand the question. It is not clear to me what you mean by `place parameter in the %ImgSize inheritance`. I had a quick perusal of the [docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) because I wasn't familiar with placeholder-selectors (`%ImgSize`). As far as I know `@extend` does not support parameters (as `@mixin` does). You could use custom css variables (`--my-var: some value;`) which can also be used in calc functions. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. In principle, I would like to use another mixin within a mixin. This would allow me to replace @extend %ImgSize with @mixin ImgSize($parameter) and combine the function from the two classes or outsource it to one. 

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use any other mixins within the mixin. I am not allowed to use any parameters with the derivation. I hope it's a bit clearer now.

`code`

Answer (score 0):

Should looks like this (dont work):

```
@mixin imageSize($theme) {
  .someClass {
    @include ImgSize (2px);
  }

  .someClass2 {
    @include ImgSize (5px);
  }
}
 @mixin ImgSize {
    // some calculations with different variables
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).